# how to use convex-hull concept to solve this problem

Tags: c++, algorithm, computational-geometry, convex-hull

I was solving  this [SPOJ problem](https://www.spoj.com/problems/VMILI/) which uses concept of convex hull.

**Go through the above link to understand the question completely**

If this problem is changed a little bit and we are given a point say A(x,y)  and asked to find maximum number of fences only around that particular point .

**My Approach**

(Correct me if i am wrong)

1.Find the maximum number of non-intersecting ,non-touching convex hulls that can be formed from N      points(given in the problem)

2.Find the number of hulls for which the the point A lies inside it.

Please help me how to approach this problem ??

*P.S.* :- I couldn't find any similar problem so that i could validate my approach . If you find
any similar problem do attach below.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach works fine.  Both your problem and the SPOJ problem can be considered recursively as follows.

Given a set of poles:

1. determine the best possible outer-most fence
2. Solve the problem again with the poles inside that fence

Note that adding another pole to the problem will never lead to a worse result, because you can always just not use it.

So, in step (1), the convex hull of the available poles is *always* a valid choice, because the set of poles inside it is a superset of the poles remaining after any other choice.  For your problem, it will also enclose the point A if any other choice does.

Comment: Thanks for answering . It would be great if you could refer to some problems that uses above concept .